# What's the point of the use function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, try-with-resources

I'm trying to use the inline function `use` with a FileInputStream instead of the classic try/catch IOException so that

```
try {
    val is = FileInputStream(file) 
    // file handling...
}
catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

becomes

```
FileInputStream(file).use { fis ->
    // do stuff with file
}
```

My question is, why use the function `use` if it stills throws exception? Do I have to wrap `use` in a try/catch? This seems ridiculous.

Comment: File is not a managed resource and java don't know when to free it. It is not managed by Garbage Collector. You need to close it correctly. It's done whether it failed or not.

Comment: `use` is equivalent of `try-with-resources` from java 7

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 3):

From Kotlin documentation:

> Executes the given block function on this resource and then closes it
>   down correctly whether an exception is thrown or not.

When you use an object that implements the *Closeable* interface, you need to call the *close()* method when you are done with it, so it releases any system resources associated with the object.

You need to be careful and close it even when an exception is thrown. In this kind of situation that is error prone, cause you might not know or forget to handle it properly, it is better to automate this pattern. That's exactly what the *use* function does.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try-catch` does not close the resource so you are comparing apples to oranges. If you close the resource in `finally` block:

```
val is = FileInputStream(file)
try {
    ...
} 
catch (e: IOException) {
    ...
}
finally {
    is.close()
}
```

is definitely more verbose than `use` which handles closing the resource.

Comment: It's more like try-with-resources. `try(val is = FileInputStream(file)) {...}`

Comment: @AccessDenied can you explain how `val is` could be null? I'm new to Kotlin, perhaps I'm missing something.